# How many numbers divide $n$?

Tags: number-theory

My questions started with a random homework dump from Stack Exchange (sadly closed):

Someone posted code that performs $n$ operations for each $i \in \{1 \dots n\}$ that divides $n$, asking about its overall complexity.

In itself, that question was not very interesting. But I thought it does hold some interesting problem: given $n \in  \mathbb{N} $, how many numbers divide $n$?

Consider the following:

$\bullet$  $D(n) = \{$number of divisors of $n$   $ \}$

$\bullet$  for $n$ that is prime, $D(n) = 2$ ($n$ and $ 1$)

Therefore, there is probably little hope finding a closed expression for $D(n)$. How about an asymptotic bound?

---

$\mathbf{Lower}$  $\mathbf{Bound:}$

Let $n$ be some non-prime natural number.

$\bullet $ $p_i$ denotes the $i$-th prime number

$\bullet $ $\alpha_i$ denotes the number of times $p_i$ occurs in the factorization of $n$. For such primes $p_j$ that don't occur at all, $\alpha_j = 0$

$\bullet $ $p_t$ denotes the largest prime number that divides $n$

The factorization of $n$ is given by:

$$n=p_1^{\alpha_1}*p_2^{\alpha_2} *p_3^{\alpha_3} \dots *p_t^{\alpha_t}$$

Example:

the factorization of $18$ is given by:

$$18=2^{1}*3^{2} $$

It is clear then, that since for any $p_i$, $p_i \geq 2$:

$$ p_1^{\alpha_1}*p_2^{\alpha_2} \dots p_t^{\alpha_t}\geq 2^{\alpha_1 + \alpha_2 \dots + \alpha_t } $$

Which gives us the lower bound: $$D(n) = \Omega (\log(n))$$

---

And here is my question: can we find an upper bound for $D(n)$? Is there a similar way to prove $D(n) = O(\log(n))$, and that the bound is tight?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_function#Growth_rate

Answer (score 1):

A classical result is that for all $n$, 
$$\sum_{k \leq n} D(k)= n \ln(n) 
+ (2\gamma-1)n + O(\sqrt{n})$$